# How to subset a longtable in R and create boxplots with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, subset, plyr

Given the following example:

```
set.seed(1)
tmp.data<-data.frame(group=rep(c("x","y","z"),8),
year=rep(c(2000:2003),6),
value=runif(24, 1, 100))
```

I can create a simple boxplot with group affiliations:

```
boxplot.example<-ggplot(data=tmp.data)
boxplot.example.simple<-boxplot.example +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=group,y=value))

# plot
boxplot.example.simple
```

However I would like to create seperate Boxplots for each group and year in the same graphic.

I tried it with the group function from ggplot:

```
boxplot.example.yearly<-boxplot.example +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=year,y=value, group=group))

# plot
boxplot.example.yearly # does not work as expected
```

However the grouping did not work as expected.

I then tried to use `split` and `llply` like this:

```
require("plyr")

boxplot.example.yearly.2<-ggplot() +
llply(.data=split(tmp.data,tmp.data$year),.fun=geom_boxplot,
aes(x=year,y=value))

# Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

which might be due to the fact that the data argument was not specified within the ggplot function.

So how can I plot the boxplots into one diagramm grouped by `group` and yearly observations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'd like to produce boxplots for each group and year in the same graph, I think your dataset is ready for that and you can do the following:

```
p <- ggplot(tmp.data, aes(factor(year), fill=group, value)) 
p + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]